# How can make the mortarsmooth overlap the edge of a brick?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I want to make some cartoonish bricks.
I want the mortarsmooth a bit more natural. The problem is those thin lines of a different part of the *colorramp*.

If I change it via a *map-range node*, I am only getting full coverage when I have the  from min-point at 1; but then I have  straight lines again.
Did I miss something?

My goal is that each color is just sit in one brick by itself.

[image: the problem]

[image: quick-Ps-edit. This is what i want. the mortarsize overlapping the small colored lines]

Comment: maybe a sketch/picture how it should like would help here. Because i still don't really get it what you want..

Comment: @Chris, I made a edit, to clarify my problem.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're generating a grayscale brick texture, then apply a color ramp to convert various shades of grey to various colors. It works only as the mortar color and each brick color is unique. Once you smooth the mortar, part of the range of its color *"leaks"* into the luminosity of other bricks...

So if I understand your problem correctly, you can solve it by using two *Brick Textures* - one generating the bricks with no mortar, and the other generating only the mortar. Then use the latter as a mask:

[image]

Using a Custom Group just to keep all the common settings in a single place:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i understand it a way better now.
i build what you explained, but i have a followup question:
but is there a chance to get a clean edge in this easy setup?

Comment: @vp.gestaltung I think applying some threshold (not necessarily 0.5) would work. https://i.imgur.com/UXqh5St.png

Comment: Awesome, i am amazed how simple it was!

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* similar approach to [@Markus von Broady's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254075/35559).. (answering at the same time :) ) .. but perhaps it's different enough to be worth posting.

It branches a parallel *Brick Texture*, in monochrome, concerned only with mortar. In the second branch, the mortar is enlarged, and softened. (That's a 'distance from rectangle edge' function, internally.) The softened mortar is multiplied with some kind of greyscale noise, and put through a threshold, to generate a mask. The mask mixes between your chosen mortar color and the original *Bricks*:

[image]

All the spaghetti is just to keep the textures in sync. There are some parameters which have no inputs, so can't be exposed in the group interface. Those are paired using drivers. To adjust those, you would have to make the group single-user, go inside, and tweak in the top texture node.

[image]

Of course, you may want to change .. e.g...  the kind of noise, to change the characteristic bleed. For more control than this sort of thing though, IMO, it would be better to create our own procedural toon bricks from scratch.

Here's a .blend with the above example settings.

[image]

Comment: Great setup, thanks a lot.

how exactly did you set up that those two bricknodes are matching certain parameters?
by trial and error i found out, it has something to to with the driver-editor, but its a complete new field for me. maybe you can give me a small insight? (:

Comment: @vp.gestaltung   Right-click in source field > 'Copy as New Driver'. Right-click in target field > 'Paste Driver'. It can get more elaborate than that, with the editor to adjust, but this is a simple one, with a 1:1 relationship. Works in just about any other field in the UI.

Comment: Great, learned something new today, I think i will benefit from it in the future.